# How to calculate Euclidean distance between a tuple and each tuple in a Vector using map in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between a tuple and each tuple within a Vector in Julia using the `map` function, like below (but I get two values instead of three):

```
julia> tups = [
         (1, 3),
         (11, 2),
         (0, 1)
       ];

julia> map((x, y) -> √(sum((x.-y).^2)), tups, (3, 3))
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 8.06225774829855
```

How can I make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Julia has the Distances package especially for these types of calculations. The 'Julian way' encourages interoperability between packages to allow benefitting from future development of the ecosystem. For example, new metric definitions, or specialized hardware code to compute distances.

For the problem in the post, the code would look:

```
julia> using Distances

julia> tups = [
         (1, 3),
         (11, 2),
         (0, 1)
       ];

julia> euclidean.(tups,Ref((3,3)))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 8.06225774829855
 3.605551275463989
```

Notice the use of broadcasting instead of `map` with dot syntax `euclidean.`. The `Ref((3,3))` causes broadcasting to consider `(3,3)` as a single element to broadcast and not break it to a pair of Ints.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written is pretty equal to this:

```
[
    func((1, 3), 3),
    func((11, 2), 3)
]
```

The [`map`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.map) function iterates over the given collections iter times equal to the lowest length:

```
julia> length((3, 3)), length(tups)
(2, 3)
```

So it iterates two times, not three. To make that work, you can repeat the (3, 3), three times or even omit the (3, 3) argument:

```
julia> map((x, y) -> √(sum((x.-y).^2)), tups, ((3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3)))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 8.06225774829855
 3.605551275463989

 # OR

julia>  map((x, y) -> √(sum((x.-y).^2)), tups, ((3, 3) for _∈1:3))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 8.06225774829855
 3.605551275463989

 # Or omit the last argument

julia> map(arg -> √((3 - arg[1])^2 + (3 - arg[2])^2), tups)
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 8.06225774829855
 3.605551275463989
```